# How to set block_encryption_mode for specific session based on user?

Tags: mysql

I am trying to set the block encryption mode specific to a session based on the user but getting error on this command:

```
IF(SELECT CURRENT_USER()) = 'root' 
THEN SET SESSION block_encryption_mode = 'aes-256-cbc'
END IF;
```

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that
> corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use
> near 'SELECT CURRENT_USER()) = 'root'  THEN SET SESSION
> block_encryption_mode = 'aes-2' at line 1

How do I resolve this ?

Comment: `IF CURRENT_USER() = 'root' ...` ? Or maybe simply add a space between your `IF` and your bracket?

Comment: The error message does not have anything to do with setting the variable, the syntax error occurs right after the if key word. Is this statement part of a stored procedure / function?